# elasticsearch temporary crash when heavily adding/updating

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running elasticsearch on a dedicated server on a Saas platform. The problem is that when cron jobs execute, and massively update/insert new values in elastic search, the front-office(the site) when it tries to connect to elasticsearch it returns false (the connection fails).

Anyone knows what can be the problem and how it can be fixed? We are running elasticsearch latest stable elastic search version.

This happens on and off, meaning when i refresh the page in the front office sometimes it cannot connect to elastic search, after another refresh it works again and so on, until the heavy load passes.

We have nvme hdds and elastic search is only running on that server not multi-nodes.

When i say heavily, I mean 1000-2000 updates per second.

Comment: how many RAM and CPUs do you have? Don’t think problem is with hdd, maybe jvm heap or not enough cpu resources for such load

Comment: The processor is: Intel® Xeon® W-2145 Octa-Core Skylake W,  with 256gb ram, only one CPU, 16 threads/8cores. Server is not at full load or RAM

Comment: @PepeleaRazvanIonut did you check the GC logs and ES logs

Comment: what about jvm heap in yml? put it 30g and 30g and try again

Comment: @DejanMarić it is already 30g.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal we had [GC (Allocation Failure)], any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: @PepeleaRazvanIonut https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/heap-sizing.html is an official guide on how to tune JVM for Elasticsearch.. please try this and let us know how useful it was